# Why won't ant run my unit tests correctly?

Tags: ant, junit

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a project using ant. For some reason, I can't get the junit tests to run. I set up a simple dummy project using ant to try and figure this out. All it has is a single unit test that should pass trivially.

My project structure looks like this.

```
.
|-- build.xml
|-- src
`-- test
    |-- foo
    |   `-- MainTest.java
    `-- junit-4.10.jar
```

`MainTest.java` looks like this.

```
package foo;

import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class MainTest {
    @Test
    public void passes() {
        System.out.println("It works!");
    }
}
```

And here is build.xml.

```
<project name="Nes" default="build" basedir=".">
    <target name="build-test">
        <javac srcdir="test">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="test/junit-4.10.jar" />
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="build-test">
        <junit>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="test/junit-4.10.jar" />
            </classpath>
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="test" includes="foo/MainTest.class" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

Here's the output I get from running `ant test`.

```
Buildfile: /home/hayden/dev/nes/build.xml

build-test:
    [javac] /home/hayden/dev/nes/build.xml:4: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds

test:
    [junit] Test foo.MainTest FAILED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

I'm running ant 1.8.2 and Java 6.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: While it's helpful that you posted a GitHub link, even better would be to include all the relevant code/information in your question here on Stack Overflow, because then the questions and answers on this site become self-contained, and then they don't have dependencies on external sources of information that may or may not be down/available/disappear/etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a path to the actual `.class` file so JUnit can actually run the test. Since you are fully qualifying the test class name, you need to include the directory that contains the `foo` package:

```
<target name="test" depends="build-test">
    <junit>
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="test/junit-4.10.jar" />
            <pathelement location="test" />
        </classpath>
```

But I'd recommend that you change the `javac` task to not output build artifacts (i.e. `.class` files) into the same directory as your source files. Create a top-level "build" directory and put all your build output in there.

You should also quiet the first warning by adding a `includeantruntime` attribute to the `javac` task:

```
    <javac srcdir="test" includeantruntime="false">
```

Comment: I'm aware of the best practices I'm violating. I was just trying to get the test to run. I wasn't aware that I needed to include the compiled test classes in the classpath, since I was specifying a path to `MainTest.class` in the `batchtest` element.